# How to call a post method using a action link in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need to call post method in my controller and I am using HTML.ActionLink in my view.

```
@HTML.ActionLink("EditUser","User");

[HTTpVerbs.Post]
Public ActionResult EditUser()
{...}
```

But it is always fetching me with

```
[HTTPVerbs.Get]
Public ActionResult EditUser()
{...}
```

Comment: Trying to figure out the full context without seeing your code is difficult. You could get speculative answers all day and have none of them actually address what you want to know.

Comment: @samack I am a new entrant into this MVC stuff. I have found some articles on this and am going forward.. Let me clearly put the requirement. I have a HTMl.Action link clicking on that action link it should call a method in my controller [HTTpVerbs.Post] Public ActionResult EditUser(){}.. but instead it is always calling Get method of EditUser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't directly.

The longer answer is that you will need to write an ajax javascript method to do so.  Something like:

```
<a onclick="dopost()"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function dopost() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ... ,
            data: ...,
            success: ...,
            dataType: ...
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You don't need to make it ajax, a simple form.submit() should be enough, but it requires a form, beside a link.

Comment: This won't work - it's either `href="javascript:dopost()"` or `onclick="dopost()"`. However, binding it from the script itself (`$('#button').click(function() { ... })`) is preferred to either of those solutions

Comment: @MikeSW - The assumption is that there is no form, otherwise they would use a submit button.  Also, a submit button actually causes the page to navigate to wherever you are submitting, which may not be what is wanted.